# wrong paperclip url for images on s3 using spree gem for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, paperclip, spree

I have an online store up and running on my own production server.  I am using Rails 4, Spree 2-1-stable, and AWS S3 for storing images.

I am now trying to move the site to aws ec2.  Everything seems to be working the same except that my image urls have changed:  What used to be:

```
src="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/public/spree/products/24/small/image.jpg"
```

is now:

```
src="/images/://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/public/spree/products/24/small/image.jpg"
```

The only changes I made to the source code was adding the `aws-ses` gem and configuring actionMailer to use SES.

The server configuration is pretty much identical too.  For the most part I just copy-and-pasted everything over.

I transferred the database using pgdump.

Any theories would be welcome.  Thanks

Comment: can you add the template code creating the output?

Comment: ```https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/products/_image.html.erb```  I guess.

Comment: the way it looks is that paperclip is not configured at all. it assumes its working locally and building the path like this. its using /images/:// ... because you migrated a db over with existing paperclip attachments but no configuration. thats an assumption;) you should create a new paperclip attachments and see how the url looks and where its putting the asset.

Comment: Not sure if it will solve your problem but I would recommend using Cloudfront instead of S3 to access images. S3  bucket can be your origin server. This will improve performance and will lower your cost.

Comment: Can you shows us the paperclip configuration on the relevant model?